# Delete pointer elements in QVector without reducing the vector size

Tags: c++, qt

I have a 20 sized `QVector` filled with `nullptr`'s, I want to change some of the `nullptr`'s with objects and when I'm done, I want to `delete` them but without reducing the vector's size.

Here's an example of what I tried:

```cpp
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    //I declare a QVector, sized 20 and filled with nullptr's
    QVector<int*> exVector(20, nullptr);

    //outs 20
    qDebug() << exVector.size();


    int* num1 = new int(4);
    exVector[2] = num1;


    int* numToDel = exVector.takeAt(2);
    exVector[2] = nullptr;
    delete numToDel;


    //outs 19
    qDebug() << exVector.size();
}
```

How can I delete the element at the 2nd index without shifting the elements in the vector and reducing its size?

Edit: the problem in this example is the `takeAt` function as @Someprogrammerdude mentioned.

Comment: Can you clarify why you use `exVector.takeAt(2)` which removes element from the vector  as the name implies, instead of `exVector[2]` to get the pointer without removing? Ie, what is the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to act on a value after replacing it with a new value, then `std::exchange()` is the function to use:

```
delete std::exchange(exVector[2], nullptr);
```

---

If you're able to change the type of `exVector`, you could make it hold smart pointers.  Then we delete simply by assigning a null pointer:

```
QVector<std::unique_ptr<int>> exVector;  // or QSharedPointer<int>, etc. …
⋮
exVector[2] = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `std::swap`:

```
int *numToDel = nullptr;
std::swap(numToDel, exVector[2]);
delete numToDel;
```

This prevents problems where you forget to reset `exVector[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`takeAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#takeAt) function

> **Removes the element** at index position `i` and returns it.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So the `takeAt` function remove the element, reducing the size of the vector.

If you just want to get the element at the specific index, use plain `[]` (as in `exVector[2]`) or use the [`at`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at) function (as in `exVector.at(2)`).

But [Botje's `swap` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76849782/440558) is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `optional`:

```
std::vector<std::optional<int>> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// ...

vec[2] = std::nullopt;
```